# How to determine the booting device

Tags: assembly, x86, device, boot

again I have a question that is not so easily googlable. Let's assume BIOS has loaded my bootloader from designated device, how do I now find out which device it is so I can load the rest of my os into ram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's [MBR bootstrap](http://wiki.osdev.org/MBR_%28x86%29#MBR_Bootstrap) (And possibly also otherwise? I'm not 100% sure) `DL` will contain 
the drive number i.e. you can do something like this (substitute your own memory layout and so on):

```
EntryPoint: 
    xor ax, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00
.DiskReset:
    mov ah, 0
    int 0x13
    jc .DiskReset
    mov ax, 0x50 ; load to 0x500 linear address. It has unused space up to 0x7bff
    mov es, ax
    xor bx, bx
    mov ax, 0x023B ; count = 0x3b = 59, the maximum..
    mov cx, 0x0002
    xor dh, dh ; leave (dl = drive number) intact
    int 0x13
    jnc .ReadDone
    mov si, ReadError
    call PrintString16
    jmp .DiskReset
.ReadDone:
    ; ......
```

Comment: thx a lot dude.. I never knew that's what the value in DL stands for.

Answer (score 0):

[There's actually a whole protocol between the firmware and the bootstrap program in sector #0.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/pcat-boot-process.html)  As you can see, however, most of it exists only in the pages of standards documents and not in reality.  In reality, when booting in the old PC/AT and PC98 way one uses `DL` for the firmware drive number and uses the "hidden sectors" field in the [BIOS Parameter Block](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/bios-parameter-block.html) (or, far less preferably, an "embedded block list" maintained with some form of specialist tool) for the location of the volume within the drive.

If one is bootstrapping in the new (to the x86 PC world at least) way, of course, then [things are a lot different](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/determining-boot-volume.html).  The operating system boot loader is an entry on the boot manager menu, and boot manager menu entries have a system of parameters, that are passed to the loader programs by the boot manager when they are run.  One of the parameters is the location of the boot volume, which the operating system boot loader uses to find the operating system files.  This is how Windows NT has worked for a long time, in fact.